# why is /app/config/parameters.yml added to .gitignore file in

Tags: symfony, configuration

Why is the /app/config/parameters.yml file in symfony/symfony-standard .gitignore file? I thought the live (prod) settings of a project are defined in this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, settings are defined in that file but it's added to `.gitignore` file because you don't want to store things like database password or csrf token in version control system as this is data which should be kept secret.

You have `parameters.yml.dist` file which is meant to keep placeholders for such data and running `composer install` will check if all data defined in `parameters.yml.dist` is present in `parameters.yml`. If not it will as you to provide it.

Check [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#canonical-parameters) for more info

Comment: does that mean that I have to provide these values on the live server on the fly or through jenkins (or any other CI tool)?

Comment: as stated in best practices you should keep only infrastructure related parameters in `parameters.yml`. It means that it's hard to automate this process as this is server specific. So once you add new parameter to `parameters.yml.dist` you need to add it at first deploy to `parameters.yml`. Once it's already there you don't need to do anything more